# boost async tcp client doesn't return error when writing without physical connection

Tags: c++, boost, tcp

I'm trying to use this example of blocking socket :
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/timeouts/blocking_tcp_client.cpp

**TEST**

I wanted to test its behavior so I tried to unplug my ethernet cable and keep writing every seconds.

**BEHAVIOR**

The *write* function continues to send messages without catching any error for about 20s and then finally catch an error (on tcp timeout ?). I defined my own deadline as 1s.

**PROBLEM**

It was expecting that i'd get an error at the first call of *write* function, after about 1s. Why don't I catch an error at this first call, instead of 20s later ? And is there a way to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

This is expected from TCP, and there is nothing you can do about it. TCP does not guarantee delivery, it makes a best effort attempt to ensure one.

If you want trully guaranteed delivery, you have to ACK your submission in the application code.

Comment: I'm surprised. TCP protocol doesn't imply to send an ACK for every packet sent ? I thought I would be able to say that i didn't receive this ACK at deadline time, and so consider my message didn't arrived in the specified time.

Comment: @augustin-r, no. If you are interested, you might read about TCP protocol, but if you are not, you can simply trust my word - TCP allows sending a lot of unacked packets before it begins retransmission. The numer would depened on the number of packets already acked since the beginning of session..